Broadcast a video to multiple social networks?
In a conference I would like to stream the video to multiple social networks.
Something really simple that receives an RMTP input stream and mirrors that to YouTube and 1-3 instances of PeerTube. So we can adopt PeerTube as primary platform, but still give YouTube as secondary platform for people who don't particularly care about Free/Libre software.
Premising that I know GNU/Linux and I usually do that with one of these installed in my server:

ffmpeg scripts
nginx configurations

I'm now investigating something more modern, with a simple user interface, so to do not require a system administrator to add an RMTP URL or update one.
Yes, I'm basically finding an Open Source alternative for these:

https://streamyard.com/
https://restream.io/

Requirements

Open Source software / Free software
not a local OpenBroadcasterSoftware plugin
easy to be installed (e.g. Docker)
easy to be configured
web user interface to add RMTP urls, and start/stop the streaming

I'm not really interested in online video editors or this kind of things. Just add/remove RMTP streamings from a web panel, and start/stop that streaming from the web itself would be nice. Bonus point: in Docker.
Thanks for any idea. I'm also unsure I've found the right search terms for what I want.
What I've already found
Docker Hub seems to have no multi-stream results:
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=rmtp
On GitHub I've found this, that is quite promising since it has a simple JSON configuration, so it may be simple to expand to provide a web UX:
https://github.com/michaelkamprath/multi-service-rtmp-broadcaster
But really I have not found anything ready.
